# Looping through an active record combo boxes in a form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a continuous form with 5 combo boxes in each record. How do I loop through each of these boxes when I click on a button in the active record to find if the boxes are not null. I want to loop through only the active record and not entire record set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
 Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveControl.Parent
       If TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
          If IsNull(ctl) Then
            MsgBox ctl.Name & " combo is null"
          Else
            MsgBox ctl.Value
          End If
       End If
    Next
```

Comment: Both the above solutions effects all the combo boxes in the form and not just on the active record. I am looking for a solution where it is applied only on the active record. eg) if i have 10 records in my continuous form with each record containing 5 combo boxes. I want say background color of only the 5 combo boxes of active record to change and not all the boxes in the form

Answer (score 0):

If comboboxes have similar names like cboTest1, cboTest2, etc., something like:

```
For Each x = 1 to 5
    If IsNull(Me("cboTest" & x)) Then
        MsgBox "Combobox " & x & " needs data selected."
    End If
End If
```